# Parse.com iOS [pod Parse] error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I'm building a simple app, as it is described on this tutorial: [Instagram like app](http://www.appcoda.com/instagram-app-parse-swift/)

However, I've made all the steps correctly, to the "Run the app" part, but when I ran it, the Xcode 7 (swift2) outputs this error every time I launch the app or pull to refresh:

> 2015-09-20 00:46:41.224 Paws2[1196:393571] [Error]: unauthorized (Code: 0, Version: 1.8.5)

I'm using the latest pod available and I don't know how to  bypass this issue.

Note that I've made an exactly app as described in the tutorial with the version 1.7.5 and the error was the same, so I updated the pos version to the latest.

I've names the app Paws2 on purpose, it wasn't a error, as it says in the Tutorial to name it 'Paws'.

Thanks in advance
- Regards, Ivan.

EDIT 1: I've updated cocoapods and everything else related and the error continues.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the .xcworkspace file and not .xcodeproj?

Comment: @ChaitanyaShah 100% sure

Comment: @DiogoNeves unfortunately not.

Comment: @DiogoNeves I've even tried to use older versions of parse and parseUI (1.7.5) and the same error comes out. Idk if this could be an Xcode 7 issue at all... I'll keep digging.

Comment: @user3636256 I'm on xcode 7 too, maybe you're right! anyone on a different version with the same problem?

Comment: @DiogoNeves I'm going to call Parse.com support on this one, let them be sure that their library is 100% compatible to Xcode 7 and Swift2 with bridging header (which is what I'm using), maybe if someone uses this on Objective C this should work properly. I'm all ears now !! :D

Comment: This is embarrassing but just in case you're having the same problem... I compared the two keys with Parse but I didn't recopy them and had an extra "t" in my code... all working now.

Comment: :O    I'll check it out for sure. I don't think I've miss-copy the key, but I didn't re-checked it at all as well so I'll give it a try. Abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same error too.
My case was silly. I put wrong Application ID / Client Key in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method on AppDelegate.

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@“Your Application ID"
              clientKey:@“Your Client Key"];
```

Make sure you put right keys.

Comment: I'll take a look today, maybe I'll have to generate a new key, because you cannot see it after the generation time, they just show the last characters

Comment: Well, I've checked it up and the key was the same, I've even generated a new one to be sure but the error still continues.

Comment: Well it's solved. I had put the wrong Application ID into the method. All good now. Thanks for the support and help